# Suppression of reference errors in VS database project not working

Tags: visual-studio-2019, sql-server-data-project, ssdt-2019

I would like to suppress all SQL71561 errors in my database project. There are a lot of views that are built in this database that reference tables from another. However, it is not feasible for me to import that other database into a DB project, nor maintain the DACPAC file for it.

I have added the error number in the "Suppress Transact-SQL warnings" field in the project properties under the Build section as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685139/suppress-database-project-errors-and-warnings-in-visual-studio-2010) answer suggested. I have tried both "SQL71561" and "71561" without success.

Anybody know what I am doing wrong?

[image: Build setup and persisting error]